# Lowercase images names in Docker

Tags: docker

Why does Docker only allow lowercase letters for image names?

Why not uppercase letters?

During the commit of a container:

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was a design choice; *technically*, there should probably be no real issues with allowing mixed-case names, but we decided to stick with lowercase for now (which keeps the road open to allow uppercase characters in future, without breaking backward compatibility).

Comment: It's a silly design choice.  There is no practical reason to restrict naming in such a fashion.

Comment: The docs state that capital letters are ok. Did this change? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description

Comment: The tag is allowed to have upper and lowercase characters, but the image name itself not. So `foobar:ABC` is allowed, but `FOOBAR:abc` not

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the docker hostname is case sensitive.

The container name (hostname) is docker-Linux.

```sh
ping docker-linux
Ping request could not find host docker-Linux. Please check the name and try again.

ping docker-Linux
64 bytes from docker-Linux (10.10.10.10): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
```