# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error : while containerizing my java web app

Tags: java, maven, docker, servlets

I am containerising my java web app, I am using spotify plugin to do so and using maven to build my project. But when I run `mvn clean package docker:build` it shows this error :

**alesblaze** is my docker hub's username

**Bookstore** is my project's name

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default) on project
>   Bookstore: Exception caught: Request error: POST
>   http://localhost:2375/build?t=alesblaze%2FBookstore: 500, body:
>   {"message":"invalid reference format: repository name must be
>   lowercase"}: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /volume/webapp/
COPY /target/BookStore-1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
RUN sh -c 'touch /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war'
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c" , "java -Djava.security.edg=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war]
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.codejava.javaee.bookstore</groupId>
  <artifactId>Bookstore</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
    <docker.image.prefix>alesblaze</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
        <finalName>BookStore</finalName>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
    <dockerDirectory>Docker</dockerDirectory>
    <dockerHost>http://localhost:2375</dockerHost>
    <forceTags>true</forceTags>
    <imageTags>
    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
    <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
    </imageTags>
    <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
    <registryUrl>https://hub.docker.com/</registryUrl>
    <resources>
    <resource>
    <targetPath>/</targetPath>
    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
    <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
    </resource>
    </resources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
    <goal>build</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: No, there is not any test running!

Comment: "invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase" says it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image name (i.e. `Bookstore`) must be lowercase. See [Lowercase images names in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858837/lowercase-images-names-in-docker)

If you run:

```
 docker build -t Bookstore
```

you get the same error

```
invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

Try to change the `artifactId` `Bookstore` to lowercase.